# Facebook Messenger bot Send Location button with redirect to the map

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

Now I am building the Facebook Messenger Bot at NodeJS and to provide some information I need to know a user location. I have the button "Send Location" and the response with a small instruction how to send manually the location: go to the menu, find an icon and push it. But reality I need that the user just click the Send Location button and automatically redirect to the map where he can just click Current Location and the bot can catch his coordinates.
Do you have some ideas how it can be made?
PS I saw this button in the "Hi Poncho" and it works great.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lib4.png)

Comment: Can you attach screenshot with that button in "Poncho" bot?

Comment: Dmitry, I added the link for an image not from Poncho (it is down now) and form Matthew's bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see similar functionality on my Bot when using the IOS messenger app.

The 'location' feature allows the user to send a their location to the bot.  By default, it showe a map with 'Your Location' and 'Tap to view on map'.  The lat/long details are sent in the background to the Bot.

I tried from the desktop and it didn't show the quick reply 'send location' button at all.

The bot is running at [DMS Software Bot.](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions)  Type 'quick reply' and hit location.

The source is at [FB-Robot](https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot) on github.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. It is really a little bit crazy ))

Comment: An up vote would be appreciated. Good luck with your Bot!